# Content over footer when converting to pdf using XML Mind Dita Converter

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop, dita

I'm new to ditac, xml, etc., so it's a bit hard for me to find the culprit.

I'm using custom xsl, ditac implementation for generating pdfs using fop and converting ditamaps using XML Mind. This was not developed by me, so it becomes hard to find the right xmls responsible for the problem. The problem is that the content (p, ul/li, ol/li, table rows) is randomly covering the footer section. The footer itself is static, it's just the text that goes over it.

I'm not sure I can share the code as it was not written by me, but if I could get some hints on where to search and what to look for.

This is a representation of the problem:
[image: footer with body text]

Comment: If content overlaps with the footer in many pages, there's a chance the `region-body`'s bottom margin is less than the `region-after`'s extent, or the footer content is taller than `region-after`'s extent, so it "overflows" covering the body region; another possible culprit is a `keep-*` property glueing together too many objects, which then invade the footer area.

Comment: If you save the FO file, trim it down to a short example showing the problem (a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and [edit] it into your question it will be easier for other people to suggest you more precise solutions; moreover, it may be that doing so will make you see the source of the problem.

Comment: @lfurini Thanks a lot! It's working, I've had only one occurrence in the following situation:
    <ol>  
      <li>  
  <ul>  
   <li>text  
    <note>text</note>  
   </li>  
   <li>**text**</li>  
  </ul>  
 </li>  
</ol>  

The last li's text overlaps with the footer, tried to investigate but no luck. When the region-body's bottom margin is 1in this is not happening, when set to 0.9in, the footer gets overlapped in the above situation, not always. The region-after extent is 0.4in.